# difference between md5 and iso

Tags: iso-image

What exactly is the difference between an md5 and an iso. disadvantages and advantages of both?

Comment: Md5 is a hash - iso is a disk image.

Comment: An MD5 file is about 1KB and an ISO is about 700MB.

Comment: Just imagine if we could reverse an md5, eh? :P

Comment: @Phoshi: i'm not downloading that movie, i'm decompressing this hash.

Comment: wonderful... sounds like I can "calculate" the ISO when I'm given only the MD5

Comment: @Phoshi - Imagine if you could reverse an ISO. (Oh, wait!  You can -- Paul is dead.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An MD5 is an 128bit hash value (such as `49f68a5c8493ec2c0bf489821c21fc3b`), wheras an ISO file is a "disk image" - effectively a file containing the same data as a physical disk would. You're comparing the sticker on an apple to an orange, here - the two are not related. You may find ISO files that come with an MD5, as each file has a unique hash (Well, unique enough that it can be used for verification), and so a corrupt download (though *not* one tampered with--that is, it's valid to use MD5 for integrity checks, but not validation or security) will not return the same hash as the original file.

Comment: It is misleading to mention MD5 as suitable for verifying the [integrity (using the PKI definition)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700808.aspx), since it is broken.

Comment: @ysangkok: While this is undeniably *true*, and I would never advocate using MD5 for, well, anything at all in a new project, I feel it does still provide "good enough" verification to defend against data corruption. It's a hideously broken algorithm, true, but not so broken that it's very likely for random changes to retain the same hash.

Comment: Yes, for checksumming it's great. But you specifically mentioned tampering. Which is the situation where you need exactly the security goal *integrity*, which MD5 does not provide since is it feasible to construct collisions.

Comment: @ysangkok: Oh, hm, so I do. I'm not sure that's a very defensible position at all. I'll edit the answer to make this clear. On the subject of checksumming, though, I discourage the use of MD5 there too--as it is, regardless of how broken, a cryptographic hash it is designed to be slower than a non-cryptographic hash, which can checksum data *much* faster with acceptable collisions.

Answer (score 1):

When you download disk images like iso there is *.md5 included!

The md5 is a hash of the related iso in order to verify its integrity! So when you download a disk image you compute `$ md5 image.iso` and compare what you get with the given md5 hash! If they match then your disk image probably doesn't have any errors!

Comment: You're the William Shatner of exclamation points.

Comment: Either that or a 14-year-old girl.  OMG!!